# git pull rebase while keeping remote on the top

Tags: git, rebase

I have a local repo with commits A B C and remote repo with commits D E F. there is nothing common in their histories.

I want a pull remote commits and put them on the top of local commits so that finally I have:
A B C D E F with F being HEAD

I tried git pull --rebase but it puts local on the top: D E F A B C

How can get remote on the top of local with repo ignoring their different histories?

Answer (score 2):

`git pull --rebase` is the combination of `git fetch` and `git rebase origin/<branch>` of course it does it that way because you can not push your changes below changes already on the server, without rewriting the server history and therefore brake everyone else's branches.

If you really need to do this:

1. `git checkout -b <new> origin/<branch>` create new branch with D E F
2. `git rebase <branch>` rebase onto A B C

Comment: I am having merge conflicts, when I followed your solution. What can I do from here?

Comment: just resolve the conflicts like you do in any merge or rebase. `git status` will tell you what to do. you would have gotten the conflicts any other way.

Comment: I resolved all the conflicts. rebase was successful .now when I run git status I get 
Your branch and 'origin/main' have diverged,
and have 15 and 12 different commits each, respectively.

Comment: this is what I warned you about. you now have to overwrite the history on the server and brake all branches started from there. The 12 should only be there if DEF consists of 12 commits! If you are sure you need to do this, do `git push --force-with-lease`

Answer (score 0):

What I can infer from your case, let's assume the following history exists and the current branch is "local":

```
      A---B---C local
     /
D---E---F <master/remote>
```

You can perform the following two things.

From this point, the result of either of the following commands: you can checkout the branch and rebase the remote on to the branch.

```
git rebase master
git rebase master local_branch
```

---

```
              A'--B'--C' topic
             /
    D---E---F master
```

NOTE: The latter form is just a short-hand of `git checkout topic` followed by `git rebase master`. When rebase exits topic will remain the checked-out branch.